# Why do resource files "disappear" from the WPF Designer when referenced from a Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Stackoverflow has other similar questions, but they seem to be related to usage in multiple assemblies or with the formatting of `ResourceDictionary` `Source` values.  This question relates to single assemblies and the tests listed at the end demonstrate the `Source` value works as-is.

The following describes a small test application that illustrates the issue.

The test application has a style XAML file (`MyStyle.xaml`):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns  ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColorKey" Color="DarkBlue" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Which is used in a UserControl (`PanelChoice.xaml`):

```
<ToggleButton 
    x:Class="PanelNS.PanelChoice"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="30"  Width="100" Background="Orange"
>
    <ToggleButton.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColorKey" Color="Yellow" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ToggleButton.Resources>

    <TextBlock 
        Foreground="{StaticResource FontColorKey}" 
        Background="Pink"  Text="Testing"
    />
</ToggleButton>
```

Which, in turn, is used on a test Window (`MainWindow.xaml`):

```
<Window x:Class="IncludeStyleTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PanelNS"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200"
>
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <local:PanelChoice />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Tests to isolate this issue:

1. This code compiles and when run displays green, orange and pink rectangles with yellow text in the middle (as expected).
2. Viewing `PanelChoice.xaml` in the XAML Designer shows orange and pink rectangles with yellow text in the middle (as expected).
3. However, viewing `MainWindow.xaml` in the designer shows `Cannot create an instance of "PanelChoice"` and lists `Cannot locate resource 'styles/mystyle.xaml'.` in the Visual Studio Error List pane.
4. If the `<ResourceDictionary  Source="/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>` line in `PanelChoice.xaml` is removed (or commented out) and the project rebuilt, then viewing `MainWindow.xaml` in the designer shows green, orange and pink rectangles with yellow text in the middle and no error messages.  It behaves as #1 when run.
5. To verify that `MyStyle.xaml` is properly referenced one can remove the `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColorKey" Color="Yellow" />` line in `PanelChoice.xaml` instead of removing `MyStyle.xaml`.  This case behaves just as #1, but the text is dark blue instead of yellow.  This demonstrates that `MyStyle.xaml` is properly referenced and is accessible.

NOTE: Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 both exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the leading / in the .xaml reference so that it looks like this instead:

```
<ResourceDictionary  Source="Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
```

The control is then able to be displayed properly in the `Window` when in the designer.

[image]

Another way to get it to show properly is to use the full physical path (you wouldn't do it this way, but just demonstrating the behaviour) e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary  Source="\Users\colin.smith\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp15\WpfApp15\Styles\MyStyle.xaml"/>
```

Yey another way that works:

```
<ResourceDictionary  Source="/WpfApp15;component/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
```

If you use the property picker to select the `Source` for your `ResourceDictionary` it does not put a leading / at the start of the `Source` when referring to the `MyStyle.xaml` that is in your `Styles` folder.

[image]

The issue seems to be with the designer. When it's providing a design surface which has to "include" another control which you have created in "the same" project, it must be doing something wrong when referring to those `ResourceDictionaries` with leading / paths.

Another way to get it to work...

If you move/create your "controls" in a separate "User Control" or "Custom Control" library, then you will be using a "pack" reference to refer to the resources...and the `Window` will be able to display that control properly in the designer.

I'm sure you can find an example of creating user controls in their own library...but will quickly show what it would kinda look like.

```
    <ToggleButton 
    x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1
.PanelChoice"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="30"  Width="100" Background="Orange"
>
        <ToggleButton.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary >
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColorKey" Color="Yellow" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ToggleButton.Resources>

        <TextBlock 
        Foreground="{StaticResource FontColorKey}" 
        Background="Pink"  Text="Testing"
    />
    </ToggleButton>
```

Then add reference to your WpfControlLibrary1 library, and use:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp15"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid Background="Green">
        <controls:PanelChoice />
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  You are correct. It sure looks like the MS reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says to use a leading slash, and it works enough to lead you down the garden path. I will certainly mark your answer as accepted; I would up the count, but I'm not quite at that reputation yet.  I appreciate your taking the time to plug the code into VS.

Comment: This question got me to the point that I can up the vote count - so I did.

Comment: As you said, it works at runtime with the / in the Source....so it's some kind of designtime issue in Visual Studio.